# How do find "echo" statement without the switch -e and replace "echo -e" in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a requirement to modify all my unix shell scripts, all occurrences and all the files in the current and sub directories as follows:

```
$ cat test.txt  ## original input file
echo "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
echo "OK"
echo -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
echo "OK!OK!!"
echo "Hello\nWorld 3"
```

To be modified as:

```
$ cat test.txt  ## desired form of file post-update
echo -e "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
echo "OK"
echo -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
echo "OK!OK!!"
echo -e "Hello\nWorld 3"
```

More details:

1. From `echo "\n...\t..."` (lines: 1 and 5, which contains backslash string but not contains "-e") to `echo -e "\n...\t..."`
2. From
   `echo -e "\n...\t.."` (line: 3, should not add one more "-e", its already there, no need to modify this line)
3. From `echo "...."` (lines: 2 and 4) - No changes required, because the lines doesn't contains any backslash characters.

Need to replace `echo` with `echo -e` in all occurrences in all files statements:

- if the "echo statements" contains any of backslash characters but without "-e" with switch.

Need NOT replace:

- if the `echo` statements contains any of backslash characters but already `echo -e`, no need to change
- if the "echo" statements DOES NOT contains any of backslash characters, no need to add `-e` - so no need to change.

I tried:

```
$ grep -R "echo.*""\.*\\n.*" *| grep -v "echo.*-e" | sed 's/echo/& -e/g'
```

Output:

```
test.txt:echo -e "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
test.txt:echo -e "Hello\nWorld 3"
```

It just showing the lines to be modified but not modify the scripts.

Kindly someone help me on this.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: See the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- the suggested replacement is `printf '%b\n' "\n\rHello\tWorld"`; use of arguments containing backslash-escape sequences in `echo` is explicitly marked nonportable.

Comment: To find them where? In an existing script?

Comment: `sed 's/echo/& -e/g' file`

Comment: `echo -e` doesn't even work on all versions of *bash* -- if you're running in POSIX mode on a bash compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default`, or with the appropriate runtime flags set, then `echo -e` will just write `-e` to output. Which is to say: This change is may improve your scripts' compatibility with some specific shells in some specific configurations, but it's absolutely not a robust and portable approach. Use `printf` instead.

Comment: Actually I want to replace echo with echo -e which the statement contains "\n or \r or \t" and want to exclude the echo statements which already contains the "-e" switch.
@scott
I tried below:

cat test.txt

echo "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
                echo "OK"
echo -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
                echo "OK!OK!!"
echo "Hello\nWorld 3"

$ grep -R "echo.*""\.*\\n.*" *| grep -v "echo.*-e"
output:

test.txt:echo "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
test.txt:echo "Hello\nWorld 3" The same would like to modify the scripts.

Comment: Desired output in the modified test.txt file:

test.txt


echo -e "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
                echo "OK"
echo -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
                echo "OK!OK!!"
echo -e "Hello\nWorld 3"
@George

Thats works fine but adding one more "-e" for echo statements which already contains "-e"
$ sed 's/echo/& -e/g' test.txt
echo -e "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
                echo -e "OK"
echo -e -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
                echo -e "OK!OK!!"
echo -e "Hello\nWorld 3"

Comment: @Maran, show what you tried yourself *in the question*, as opposed to in comments. See the [edit] button.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Much better, though there's some editing for formatting that could be done (the `{}` button is appropriate for code formatting -- `>` is meant for quoted English text, vs quoted code). And, to be clear -- I'm still hoping to convince you that what you're asking for is *wrong* -- ie. that you're asking for something that makes your scripts needlessly nonportable, when an alternative exists that will result in a script that works correctly on all POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: Note that `sh -c 'echo -e "hello\\nworld"'` may (on MacOS, for example, *does*) print `-e hello` on one line and `world` on the other. This is an example of what I mean in saying that what you're asking for is *wrong*.

Comment: Ok, I understand and noted this point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Initial Caveats

Note that the below won't behave well with sufficiently interesting/complicated syntax -- `echo`s in command substitutions, for example; those in strings which are later `eval`ed; compound commands; commands split from their arguments across multiple lines; etc. For that reason, I strongly suggest **manually reviewing** the changes and merging them by hand (with a tool such as `git add -p` should contents be in revision control, or `vimdiff` or similar in general).

---

#### As Literally Requested

```
rewrite_echos() {
  has_echo_re='((^|;|&)[[:space:]]*)echo([[:space:]])(.*)$'
  has_echo_e_re='(^|;|&)[[:space:]]*echo[[:space:]]+-n?en?[[:space:]]+'

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $has_echo_re ]] || { printf '%s\n' "$line"; continue; }
    prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; suffix_chr=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}; content=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}

    [[ $line =~ $has_echo_e_re ]] && { printf '%s\n' "$line"; continue; }
    [[ $content = *"\\"* ]] || { printf '%s\n' "$line"; continue; }
    printf '%secho -e%s\n' "$prefix" "${suffix_chr}${content}"
  done
}
```

Running this as:

```
rewrite_echos <test.txt
```

correctly emits:

```
echo -e "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
echo "OK"
echo -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
echo "OK!OK!!"
echo -e "Hello\nWorld 3"
```

---

#### More Correct: Using `printf` instead of `echo`

Unlike the *requested* transform, the one given below generates output which works with all POSIX-compliant shells.

```
rewrite_echos() {
  has_echo_re='((^|;|&)[[:space:]]*)echo([[:space:]])(.*)$'

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $has_echo_re ]] || { printf '%s\n' "$line"; continue; }
    prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; suffix_chr=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}; content=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}

    [[ $content = *"\\"* ]] || { printf '%s\n' "$line"; continue; }
    if [[ $content =~ ^-e[[:space:]] ]]; then
      printf $'%sprintf \'%%b \'%s && printf \'\\\\n\'\n' "$prefix" "${suffix_chr}${content#-e[[:space:]]}"
    else
      printf $'%sprintf \'%%b \'%s && printf \'\\\\n\'\n' "$prefix" "${suffix_chr}${content}"
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: This is what I want! It is working fine and I am able to alter my scripts using your code. Thank you so much!

Comment: Apologize to use this same thread, hope related to the same question.

Kindly let me know, if I need to open new ticket.

cat test.txt  ## original input file
echo "\nHello\n\tWorld 1"
echo -e "\nHello\nWorld 2"
echo "Hello\nWorld 3"
Erreur=`echo $?`
 case $Erreur in
  0) echo  "Status:         OK" 
  1)  echo  "\033[41mStatus NOTOK\033[0m" 
  *) echo  "\033[41mStatus  NOTOK\033[0m" 
  exit 30;;
    esac

 
The function is working fine for contents. But the "case" part not working for me.
I don't know, where to change in the function logic.
Could you please help me?

Comment: See the "initial caveats" section. `case` is a compound command, which is deliberately out of scope for this answer. You'd need something like https://github.com/mvdan/sh to do it right.

Comment: Thank you, I will try some other method.